# How to get resovled value from $routeProvider in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

On change of views in my application i  created resolve function which should find out if user is logged in or not:

```
   $routeProvider.
            when('/taskoverview', {
                templateUrl: 'Home/Template/taskoverview', resolve: TaskOverviewCtrl.resolve, access: { allowAnonymous: true },
                resolve: {
                    userAuthenticated: ["$http", function ($http) {
                        var loggedIn;
                        $http.get('/api/Authentication/UserAuthenticated').then(function (data) {
                            if (data.data != null) {
                                loggedIn = true;
                            }
                            else {
                                loggedIn = false;
                                console.log("really");
                            }   
                        });
                        return loggedIn;

                    }]
                }
            }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

After it happend i want to check value of userAuthenticated on locationChangeStart, so i thought it should be pretty much straign forward.

```
WorkerApp.run(function ($rootScope, $routeParams, $route, $location) {
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            for (var i in $route.routes) {
                if (next.indexOf(i) != -1) {
                    if ($route.routes[i].access != null && ($route.routes[i].userAuthenticated != null || typeof($route.routes[i].userAuthenticated) != "undefined")) {
                            if ((!$route.routes[i].access.allowAnonymous || $route.routes[i].access.allowAnonymous == "undefined") && (!$route.routes[i].userAuthenticated || $route.routes[i].userAuthenticated == "undefined")) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                alert("no access");

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

        });

    });
```

But evrytime i change my userAuthenticated is always undefined. So question is, how do i make it return a value?

Are there any more straigh way to prevent user to access pages without authenticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $routeProvider.
            when('/taskoverview', {
                templateUrl: 'Home/Template/taskoverview', resolve: TaskOverviewCtrl.resolve, access: { allowAnonymous: true },
                resolve: {
                    userAuthenticated: ["$http", "$q", function ($http, $q) {
                        var deferred = $q;
                        $http.get('/api/Authentication/UserAuthenticated').then(function (data) {
                            if (data.data != null) {
                                deferred.resolve();
                            }
                            else {
                                deferred.reject();
                                console.log("really");
                            }   
                        });
                        return deferred.promise;

                    }]
                }
            }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

If you want to handle the reject you can create a $on listener for the "$routeChangeError" event like this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
  alert("Not authorised");
}
```

Comment: You need to add userAuthenticated as a dependency in your controller if you want to see it's value and in my code I didn't pass anything in the resolve so it will probably be undefined just change it to deferred.resolve(true). Also, I don't understand why do you need to do that check in the run block, if the resolve userAuthenticated returns a rejected promise the page won't load.

Comment: Problem is i dont have any controller i just have WorkerApp.run(function ($rootScope, $routeParams, $route, $location).....

Comment: As I said you don't need to check the value of userAuthenticated at run block, route will only be resolved if all of the resolved promises in the resolve are successful otherwise the $routeprovider will broadcast a $routeChangeError event.

Comment: But if i want to cast an allert or something? is it possible?

Comment: It works, but my route is changing, how do i stop it?

Comment: You can cast an alert and stop the route with an even handler as in:

      $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
        alert("not authorised");
}